# Can I download the upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 without installing it right away?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade

When it comes to regular day-today updates, I chose to download all updates in the background, and than I'll manually choose to install it.

Especially now that 11.10 was just released and it will probably take a while to download, can I do the same with the upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 ? So it will download everything in the background and once it'll finish the download, I will be able to apply the upgrade when I want to ?

Can I download the complete release (as if I'm going to do a fresh install) and use that in some way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can download the Alternate ISO, and then follow the steps of "Upgrading using the Alternate CD":

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD

PS: There is no need to burn a CD.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to accomplish this in a way, but it's a bit complicated. You would have to use Synaptic, and change all your software sources to point to oneiric instead of natty, then set it to download the packages it needs for the upgrade and not install them....

But this method could also mean that the upgrade does not go smoothly due to package solver issues.